# ionic and ruby on rails - can create account and login, but if logout and try to login again get "invalid credentials"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

i am working on ionic / ruby on rails - authentication system.

the ionic app is already able to create an account and automatic login after the account creation.

but if i logout and try to login again (using the ionic app), i get the error "invalid credentials",

if i try to login with same credentials using POSTMAN, it works all right

Could someone help me find out what is happening?

here is the ionic login/registration controller:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $stateParams, ionicMaterialInk, $auth, $state) {
    $scope.$parent.clearFabs();

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$parent.hideHeader();
    }, 0);
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();

    $scope.accountCreate = function(registrationData) {

          $auth.submitRegistration(registrationData)
            .then(function(resp) {
                console.log(resp);
              $state.go('app.publications');
            })
            .catch(function(resp) {
              $scope.error = resp;
            });
        };


    $scope.login = function(provider) {
        if (provider == 'email'){
            $auth.submitLogin($scope.registrationData)
                .then(function(resp) {
                  $state.go('app.publications');
                })
                .catch(function(resp) {
                  $scope.error = resp;
                });
            } else {
                  $auth.authenticate(provider)
                      .then(function(resp) {
                          $state.go('app.publications');

                      })
                      .catch(function(resp) {
                        $scope.error = resp;
                    });        
            }

    };    
})
```

here is the login/account-creation html:

```
<div class="list">                      
    <ion-md-input ng-model="registrationData.name" ng-show="accountCreateField" placeholder="Nome" highlight-color="energized" type="text"></ion-md-input>
    <ion-md-input ng-model="registrationData.email" placeholder="e-mail" highlight-color="balanced" type="text"></ion-md-input>
    <ion-md-input ng-model="registrationData.password" placeholder="senha" highlight-color="energized" type="password"></ion-md-input>
</div>
<div class="padding">
    <button ng-show="accountCreateField" ng-click="accountCreate(registrationData)" class="button button-full button-royal ink">Registrar</button>
    <button ng-show="!accountCreateField" ng-click="login('email')" class="button button-full button-royal ink">Login</button>
</div>
<div class="create-account">
    <button ng-show="!accountCreateField" ng-click="accountCreateField = true" class="button button-full button-energized-900 ink">Criar Conta</button>
</div>
```

Here is the log for account login:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/auth/sign_in" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-11-13 21:33:00 +0000
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as HTML
  [1m[36mSubdomain Load (28.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "subdomains".* FROM "subdomains" WHERE "subdomains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["address", ""]]
  [1m[35mDomain Load (28.4ms)[0m  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["address", "smartmarket.io"]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 60ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 57.1ms)
```

Here is the log for account creation that works and automaticaly login after:

```
Started OPTIONS "/api/v1/auth" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-11-13 21:26:05 +0000


Started POST "/api/v1/auth" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-11-13 21:26:06 +0000
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"name"=>"diogo", "email"=>"diogo@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "confirm_success_url"=>"http://git-music.org/", "config_name"=>"default", "registration"=>{"name"=>"diogo", "email"=>"diogo@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "confirm_success_url"=>"http://git-music.org/", "config_name"=>"default"}}
  [1m[36mSubdomain Load (32.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "subdomains".* FROM "subdomains" WHERE "subdomains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["address", ""]]
  [1m[35mDomain Load (49.6ms)[0m  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["address", "smartmarket.io"]]
Unpermitted parameters: confirm_success_url, config_name, registration
Unpermitted parameters: confirm_success_url, config_name, registration
Unpermitted parameters: confirm_success_url, config_name, registration
  [1m[36m (28.4ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (28.7ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."email" = $2  [["provider", "email"], ["email", "diogo@email.com"]]
  [1m[36mUser Exists (28.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'diogo@email.com' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (29.1ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "name", "tokens", "provider", "uid", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "diogo@email.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$pP7U1Tjvu9mvRgD0eeMttOG5ER6faerB8O325ATGrKPWXV0JD.K9m"], ["name", "diogo"], ["tokens", "{}"], ["provider", "email"], ["uid", "diogo@email.com"], ["created_at", "2016-11-13 21:26:06.438426"], ["updated_at", "2016-11-13 21:26:06.438426"]]
  [1m[36mSQL (28.7ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "profiles" ("name", "kind", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["name", "diogo"], ["kind", "Pagina Grátis"], ["user_id", 43], ["created_at", "2016-11-13 21:26:06.501881"], ["updated_at", "2016-11-13 21:26:06.501881"]]
  [1m[35mSQL (29.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "user_main_profiles" ("profile_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["profile_id", 35], ["user_id", 43], ["created_at", "2016-11-13 21:26:06.533324"], ["updated_at", "2016-11-13 21:26:06.533324"]]
  [1m[36mUserMainProfile Load (28.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "user_main_profiles".* FROM "user_main_profiles" WHERE "user_main_profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["user_id", 43]]
  [1m[35m (28.9ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36m (28.3ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (29.0ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'diogo@email.com' AND "users"."id" != 43) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (28.6ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "tokens" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3[0m  [["tokens", "{\"81thDt1-5BH8bnAgn-_bOQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$04D0bORhgRZWg6qcVweczu5ZcJ5kla6rY6TRTZwuqnN6IpivvnwhK\",\"expiry\":1480281966}}"], ["updated_at", "2016-11-13 21:26:06.757132"], ["id", 43]]
  [1m[35m (28.8ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36mUser Exists (28.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'diogo@email.com' AND "users"."id" != 43) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (28.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mUser Load (28.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE[0m  [["id", 43]]
  [1m[35mUser Exists (28.7ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'diogo@email.com' AND "users"."id" != 43) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (28.3ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "tokens" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3[0m  [["tokens", "{\"81thDt1-5BH8bnAgn-_bOQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$aR9ff.s6Y9zFgrGwjhnneefxJu4/WNz8aHQrt5tafPRRuJjnBl/o.\",\"expiry\":1480281967,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$04D0bORhgRZWg6qcVweczu5ZcJ5kla6rY6TRTZwuqnN6IpivvnwhK\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-11-13T21:26:07.031+00:00\"}}"], ["updated_at", "2016-11-13 21:26:07.061963"], ["id", 43]]
  [1m[35m (28.7ms)[0m  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 984ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 597.9ms)


Started OPTIONS "/api/v1/auth/validate_token" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-11-13 21:26:07 +0000


Started GET "/api/v1/auth/validate_token" for 177.207.232.141 at 2016-11-13 21:26:07 +0000
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::TokenValidationsController#validate_token as HTML
  [1m[36mSubdomain Load (28.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "subdomains".* FROM "subdomains" WHERE "subdomains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["address", ""]]
  [1m[35mDomain Load (28.6ms)[0m  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["address", "smartmarket.io"]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (28.9ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["uid", "diogo@email.com"]]
  [1m[35mUser Exists (28.9ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'diogo@email.com' AND "users"."id" != 43) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (28.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (28.8ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE  [["id", 43]]
  [1m[36mUser Exists (28.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'diogo@email.com' AND "users"."id" != 43) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (28.5ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET "tokens" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["tokens", "{\"81thDt1-5BH8bnAgn-_bOQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$aR9ff.s6Y9zFgrGwjhnneefxJu4/WNz8aHQrt5tafPRRuJjnBl/o.\",\"expiry\":1480281967,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$04D0bORhgRZWg6qcVweczu5ZcJ5kla6rY6TRTZwuqnN6IpivvnwhK\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-11-13T21:26:07.922+00:00\"}}"], ["updated_at", "2016-11-13 21:26:07.952812"], ["id", 43]]
  [1m[36m (28.5ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Completed 200 OK in 368ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 257.6ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution :)

The controller was not passing the form output to the app!

it was an ionic error:

So it was added to the controller

```
$scope.registrationData = {};
```

Here is the correct way for my app:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $stateParams, ionicMaterialInk, $auth, $state) {
    $scope.$parent.clearFabs();

    $scope.registrationData = {};

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$parent.hideHeader();
    }, 0);
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
```

And it worked fine!
thanks